# Prevent deleting element in contenteditable

Tags: internet-explorer, contenteditable

Is it possible to prevent deleting an element from contenteditable.
I have the following markup and when user presses backspace or delete key if cursor is next to image element I want the image not to be deleted and cursor to move to prev/next char.

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="true">
    some text and            
    <img id="img" src="someimg.gif"/>
    more text
</div>
```

This is IE functionality

Comment: I guess the text should be wrapped in the `p` tag with the  `contenteditable` attribute

Answer (score -3):

I think you should split contenteditable to two parts like that:

```html
<div id="content" contenteditable="true">
    some text and            
</div>
    <img id="img" src="someimg.gif"/>
<div id="content" contenteditable="true">
    more text
</div>
```